# What OSM information to use for low zoom levels to get a style similar to MapQuest

Tags: openstreetmap, tilemill, cartocss, natural-earth

I am building an outdoor map of Europe. Everything looks pretty nice when zoomed in. But when I am zoomed out, my map looks pretty boring. Most parts are white.
In low zoom levels I display polygons only at a certain size. So there aren't many polygons that I could f.e. render as a green forest or grass-lands.

Does anybody know which information f.e. the MapQuest Map uses for zoom levels form 4 - 8?

Which polygons or which information is used to render most parts of Europe and America green, or the northern part of Africa brown, the poles white and so on?

[image]

I am using a Natural-Earth raster myself for the first few zoom levels, but after I can use those.

Which OSM information could I use?

Or are there some open shapefiles I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you're looking for ways to style landuse at low/medium zoom levels, yeah?

Looks like MapQuest is currently working on a new open CartoCSS-based map style ([here](https://github.com/MapQuest/mq-carto-style-vector/tree/master/mq-carto-style.tm2)).  It's pretty bare bones still for stuff like landuse.

Also checkout [OSM's Carto styles](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto), in particular `landcover.mss`.

Also, MapBox has some good, open Carto styles.  Their [MapBox Outdoors](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-studio-outdoors.tm2) is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks for your help James. The problem ist that I can see their css but not their datasource... So I don't know what data they use for low levels?!?

Comment: Why should they use different data for lower zoom levels?

Comment: @Georg the SQL queries for each layer are defined in `project.mml`.  For example, find the SQL query for `#landcover-low-zoom` [here](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/blob/master/project.mml#L103).  The complexities of the OSM data model make the official OSM layer queries rather complex--you can probably get away with simplifying the query quite a bit.

Comment: @scai unless I'm mistaken, the openstreetmap-carto doesn't use different data for different zoom levels (though they do query the data differently at low/high zoom levels).  Not sure if MapBox Outdoors changes source data at different zoom levels.  But even if either of them did, I guess the short answer would be: because it renders better.

Comment: great... thanks... i already have my map looking much better now :)

Comment: @JamesConkling Technically Default OSM is using some special sources. For zoom levels 1, 2, 3 it is using ne border data and for 8, 9 it is using builtup areas from the same source. Usage is defined at https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/blob/master/shapefiles.mss and sources of data at https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/blob/master/get-shapefiles.sh In the past also city labels on low zoom levels were from ne, but this was eliminated.